# Unexpected TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a program from "Fluent Python" which encounter an unexpected error:

```
registry = []

def register(func):
    print("running register(%s)" % func)
    registry.append(func)

@register
def f1():
    print("runnning f1()")

@register
def f2():
    print("running f2()")

def f3():
    print("running f3()")

def main():
    print("running main()")
    print("registry ->", registry)
    f1()
    f2()
    f3()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It reported unexpected error when I run it

```
In [15]: !python registration.py
running register(<function f1 at 0x1070d9a60>)
running register(<function f2 at 0x1070dc0d0>)
running main()
registry -> [<function f1 at 0x1070d9a60>, <function f2 at 0x1070dc0d0>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "registration.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "registration.py", line 21, in main
    f1()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I double checked the error line it prompt: f1(), but truly cannot figure out any problem int he code:

Comment: In case the answer to that other question doesn't make sense for your case: you need to add `return func` as the last line of the `register` decorator.

Comment: I deeply appreciate  your kindness after my question was marked dup @MondKin

Comment: I deeply appreciate  your kindness after my question was marked dup @MondKin